# make sortable JS list from an array

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to make from an array of scrambled sentences unordered lists to apply sortable JS in the following format

```
<ul id="sortable" class="div3">
<li id = 'number'> </li>
<li id="1" class="ui-state-default">The</li>
<li id="2" class="ui-state-default">piano</li>
<li id="3" class="ui-state-default">play</li>
<li id="4" class="ui-state-default">I</li> 
</ul>
<script>
```

So far I have come up with the following which does not give the correct format

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>my array to list attempt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
li {
list-style:none;
display: inline;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
 function makeQuest() {
  var quest=['I play piano the can', 'tired I am', 'are seven there week in a days'];

  for (var i=0; i< quest.length; i++){
        document.write('<ul class ="div3">')
        document.write('<li id = "number">' + (i + 1) +  ' '+ '</li>')
    for (var j=0; j < quest[i].length; j++){
        document.write('<li>' + quest[i][j] + '</li>')
        document.write('</ul>')
            }
        }       
 };

 $(function makeSort() {
    $( ".div3" ).sortable({
      items: "li:not(#number)"

    });

    $( ".div3" ).disableSelection();

   });
</script>

<script>
 makeQuest()
 makeSort()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not a programmer : just trying to make a language tutor for personal use. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, and is sortable

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>my array to list attempt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>
        li {
            list-style:none;
            display: inline;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="sortable" class="div3">
    <li id = 'number'> </li>
    <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">The</li>
    <li id="2" class="ui-state-default">piano</li>
    <li id="3" class="ui-state-default">play</li>
    <li id="4" class="ui-state-default">I</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $(function makeSort() {
        $( ".div3" ).sortable({
            items: "li:not(#number)"

        });

        $( ".div3" ).disableSelection();

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My problem is how to get all the sentences from the array into the format necessary for sortable JS that you used.  Or does each sentence have to be formatted separately and manually?